# What are the possible dimensions of self-anti-involution matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am considering $2^n\times 2^n$ complex matrices and a general anti-involution $A^{**}=A$, $(AB)^*=B^* A^*$. To my knowledge all anti-involutions are a combination of transpose, field involution and similarity transform (is that correct?).

What are the possible dimensions of the space created by all matrices which are it's own anti-involution $$A=A^*$$ I am considering a complex number to be 2 dimensions (i.e. in real vector space).

For example for $4\times 4$ matrices and the Hermitian conjugate for the anti-involution, you have 16 independent degrees of freedom (4 reals on diagonal and 6 complex numbers above diagonal). Is calling this a 16-dimensional vector space correct?

If you were to choose the transpose as the anti-involution, you would have 20 dimensions (4 complex on diagonal and 6 complex numbers above diagonal).

However, if you chose the anti-involution $$A^*=RA^TR^{-1}$$ with $$R=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0& 0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}$$then the matrices with $A=A^*$ would form only a 12-dimensional space (correct?).

Is this the smallest dimension that self-anti-involution matrices can have? Which other values are possible?

I think, generally, for $2^n\times 2^n$ matrices you can find anti-involutions which would make the space of self-anti-involution matrices $d=2^n(2^n+(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor})$ dimensional. My main motivation is to understand if these particular anti-involutions are special in some sense. Maybe one would restrict to not using complex conjugation (the field involution) for that.